# How to maintain trees and their roots in SQLite

Tags: trigger, insert, sqlite, merge, hierarchy

I have a (SQLite) database with a table representing nodes in a forest (set of trees):

```
create table "Node" (
    "id" Text primary key,
    "parent" Text references "Node" ("id") -- parent node
        on update restrict on delete restrict,
    "root" Text references "Node" ("id") -- tree root node
        on update restrict on delete restrict
) without rowid;
```

It may happen that after inserting new nodes or updating existing ones, `"root"` attribute updates must be performed on the inserted nodes or nodes previously in the table, because the inserted nodes are connected to or existing trees.

Consider the following existing table:

```
"id" "parent" "root"
--------------------
'a'  null     'a'
'b'  'a'      'a'
'c'  'a'      'a'
```

- Case 1: we want to insert/ignore the following nodes

  ```
  "id" "parent" "root"
  --------------------
  'b'  null     'b'           -- ignore
  'd'  'b'      'b'           -- insert
  ```

  To end up with

  ```
  "id" "parent" "root"
  --------------------
  'a'  null     'a'
  'b'  'a'      'b'
  'c'  'a'      'a'
  'd'  'b'      'b'
  ```
- Case 2: we want to insert/update (in the original table, without the case 1 changes)

  ```
  "id" "parent" "root"
  --------------------
  'e'  null     'e'           -- insert
  'a'  'e'      'e'           -- update
  ```

  To end up with

  ```
  "id" "parent" "root"
  --------------------
  'e'  null     'e'
  'a'  'e'      'e'
  'b'  'a'      'e'
  'c'  'a'      'e'
  ```

Given these cases: what are insert/update statements (and perhaps triggers) that allow me to do obtain the correct resulting trees? One part is: when the node is already in the table, then I need to ‘merge’ it correctly with its version from the insert and then I need to propagate in some way the change of root.

One idea I had was to create a second table containing just a list of roots and then having `"root"` refer there, so that it could cascade on update. But then I don't know how to deal with updates that replace a root by an already existing one.

Comment: Please UPDATE your question.

Comment: @CL.: Sorry, but I do not understand what I should update exactly?

Comment: You are talking about inserting, but it is not possible to change any root this way.

Comment: @CL.: Can you explain why? Manually, I would in Case 1 insert `'d', 'b', 'a'` and update `'d'`'s `"root"` to `'a'`; in Case 2 I would insert `'e', null, 'e'` and update `'a'`'s `"parent"` to `'e'` and `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`'s `"root"` to `'e'`. I was hoping that this could be automated with the right insertion/updating approach and conflict resolution.

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify that you do not mean insert but "insert or update".

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Thanks, I guess that clarifies things for many people. I fixed a change of meaning that you effected in Case 1 without intending to. I really want to get the results I have for both cases, i.e., I want to be able to merge paths into a tree and TBH don't care how this is achieved, whether with inserts and updates only, or also with other statements.

Comment: OK, good. But I don't understand how the logic goes. Why should the `'b'  null     'b'` be ignored but the `'a'  'e'      'e'` be updated? If there's a separate flag in the data (insert/update/ignore) ok. But otherwise, how?

Comment: And how can you have `'b'  'a'      'b'` after case 1 is applied? How can `b` have `a` as a parent but itself as root? (I guess my edit mixed them up? Sorry. And you meant `'b' 'a' 'a'` as a result? Please edit accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

Finding all nodes in a subtree to update them requires a [recursive common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte):

```
-- update the root of all nodes in 'a's subtree to 'x'
WITH RECURSIVE subtree(id) AS (
    VALUES('a')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Node.id
    FROM Node
    JOIN subtree ON Node.parent = subtree.id
)
UPDATE Node
SET root = 'x'
WHERE id IN subtree;
```

In SQLite, CTEs are not allowed in triggers.